# Cannot connect two PCs connected to the same router

Tags: network-share

i have two PCs, on computer "A" i have published an asp.net web application using iis 7.5 on the local host, then i did the folloiwng :-
1. i connect computer A to one of the LAN ports on the router
2. i connect computer B to another port on the router.
3. Then on computer B i typred the folloiwng:-

```
http://A
```

which prompt a user name and password dialog , but when i inserted the user name and password for user A,, an error occured which say "unauthorized access".
So how i can do the following :-

**1. if user B typed `http://A` on his browser to be able to directly access the application published at the localhost of user A.**
BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try qualifying the user name - if it's a local user on computer A, use username A\Username. If a domain account, use DOMAIN\Username.